# Assign an integer variable to an integer variable and change name dynamic

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim LastNumber as Integer = 1
Dim num_0() as Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim num_1() as Integer = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim num_2() as Integer = {20, 21, 14, 36, 0}
Dim y() As Integer

y(0) = num_0(2)
```

When I use this code it executes perfectly

But the problem is I want to change the "0" in num_0(2)
When I do...

```
y(0) = num_ & LastNumber & (2)
```

This doesnt work
Or
    y(0) = ("num_" & LastNumber & "(2)")
This gives me an error  that converting a string to an integer is not possible

My question is How can I replace the "0" in num_0(2)  with the LastNumber integer variable... so it reads the "8" out of the array num_1(2)

Comment: Thats not how it works.  Once the compiler is done with it, `num_0` is likely named something else. You cant create variable references on the fly because the compiler must know about them at compile time.  I cant tell exactly what you are playing at, but putting them all in one array (or a List of Arrays) with other index variables indicating the start of each set as well as that `LastNumber` could work.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [multidimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93) (AKA rectangular array):

```
Dim num As Integer(,) = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {20, 21, 14, 36, 0} }

y(0) = num(LastNumber, 2)
```

or [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhhsz9t) (array of arrays) :

```
Dim num As Integer()() = { ({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), ({6, 7, 8, 9, 10}), ({20, 21, 14, 36, 0}) }

y(0) = num(LastNumber)(2)
```